# How to pass record id to the Emp API Lightning Web Component?

Tags: lightning-web-components

In my [Aura implementation of Emp API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:empApi/documentation), I could pass the record Id I want to listen for changes to like this:

```
empApi.subscribe("/topic/AllLeadChanges?Id=" + component.get("v.recordId"), -1, function(message) { ... }
```

This has the effect of only sending me updates for that particular record.

When I try the same thing with the [LWC implementation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-emp-api/documentation) of Emp API, I don't receive any updates:

```
this.channelName = '/topic/AllAccountChanges?Id=' + this.recordId;
```

However, by removing the record Id from the channel name, I receive updates as expected:

```
this.channelName = '/topic/AllAccountChanges';
```

It would appear the Emp API LWC implementation doesn't know how to handle the record Id parameter.

It is possible to pass the record Id to the LWC version of Emp API and only receive updates for a specific record?

Note, I'm essentially using the exact same implementation found in the Salesforce LWC reference:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-emp-api/documentation

Also, I'm using `PushTopic`:

```
PushTopic pushTopic=new PushTopic();
pushTopic.Name='AllAccountChanges';
pushTopic.Query='SELECT Id, Name, LastModifiedDate from Account';
pushTopic.ApiVersion=43.0;
pushTopic.NotifyForOperationCreate=true;
pushTopic.NotifyForOperationUpdate=true;
pushTopic.NotifyForOperationUndelete=true;
pushTopic.NotifyForOperationDelete=true;
pushTopic.NotifyForFields='All';
Insert pushTopic;
```

As a workaround, I am checking to see if the record ids match and only refreshing if they do:

```
// need to get a reference to "this" as the reference changes in messageCallback.
let self = this;

// callback invoked whenever a new event message is received
const messageCallback = function(response) {

    // Response contains the payload of the new message received
    console.log('New message received : ', JSON.stringify(response));

    // temporary fix for not being able to pass the id into the channel name:
    if(response.data.sobject.Id && response.data.sobject.Id === self.recordId) {
        // use the "self" reference instead of "this"
        refreshApex(self._getAccountResult);
    }
};
```